# How do I loop under Chart js in JavaScript for multiple axis?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying to loop into a chart js in order also to enable multi axis... however the function for seems to be giving an "unexpect token "for""...

```
var getData = $.get('/graphcomp');

getData.done(function() {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: getData[Lenght],
        datasets: [
          for (x in getData) {
            {
              label: x,
              data: getData[x],
              yAxisID: x,
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(0, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            },
          }

        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Process Parameters'
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            for (x in getData) {
              {
                id: x,
                type: 'linear'
              },
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You've actually got a number of issues in your code. `getData` is a Promise, not an array, so you can't loop over it, and you can't loop in the middle of an array literal. Please review the [documentation for `$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to see how it's used. Then review how to create an array from another using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get( "graphcomp", function( data ) {
 init(data);
});

function init(getData){
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: getData[Lenght],
        datasets: [
          for (x in getData) {
            {
              label: x,
              data: getData[x],
              yAxisID: x,
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(0, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(0, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            },
          }

        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Process Parameters'
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            for (x in getData) {
              {
                id: x,
                type: 'linear'
              },
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

}
```